# Class of functions with constrains on derivative

Tags: real-analysis, functions

In an article I am reading, the author considers a class of functions:

$$
\{T \in C^1(\Bbb R^+)\text{ strictly increasing; }
\ \ x\le T(x)\le xT'(x)
\}
$$

Can you give me a generic example of such a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any monomial for $n\ge1$ satisfies $x(x^n)'=nx^n\ge x^n$, and the constraint $T(x)\le xT'(x)$ is linear (w.r.t positive linear combinations), so any polynomial $\sum_{k=1}^n a_kx^k$ will satisfy this condition as long as each $a_k\ge 0$. To satisfy $x\ge T(x)$, all we need is $a_1\ge 1$.

Comment: thanks. Do you have an idea of a function with an at most polynomial increase?

Comment: @mookid Oops, I misread the OP as $xT(x)\le T'(x)$, instead of $T(x)\le xT'(x)$. Actually, most polynomials will satisfy your constraint; will edit.

Comment: @mookid the $x$ was moved across the inequality, so it actually completely changes the character of the differential equation. (You need exponentials to get a derivative which has one *more* $x$ factor in the derivative, but any polynomial can have one *less* $x$ factor in the derivative.)

Comment: exactly. I edited with only the answer, for clarity. thanks again.